# GridHyperLinkColumn - Show hyperlink text

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have the following code:

```
<telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataTextField="VerificationId" DataNavigateUrlFields="VerificationId" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Entry.aspx?VerId={0}"
    HeaderText="" UniqueName="VerificationId">  
</telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
```

I would like the hyperlink to display "View" when I change DataTextField to "View".

I am not sure how to do that with the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the text property:

```
 <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataTextField="VerificationId" DataNavigateUrlFields="VerificationId" 
           DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Entry.aspx?VerId={0}"
           HeaderText="" UniqueName="VerificationId" Text = "View">
```